# sql server date matching between 2 dates should i convert to military or use am/pm

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have in SQL Server a DateTime that looks like this

```
  2017-02-07 09:18:25.633
```

Now from C# , even with SSMS in sql in writing a query I was doing range like

```
where WebDateTime between '2/7/2017 8:19' and '2/7/2017 9:19'
```

However that is not correct because I'm not using military time (not sure if needed,  nor a AM/PM ... and thus this line fails to give results

```
where WebDateTime between '2/7/2017 8:19' and '2/7/2017 1:19'
```

Thus the  8:19 to 9:19 works,  but not  8:19 to 1:19  ,  what do i need to do in order to fix the range with the "type" of date time that i have?

Comment: I just always use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format.

Comment: From C#, use a parameterized query and pass in the `DateTime` value instead of using a string at all...

Comment: I want to have 1 hour range only , sorry for the confusion

Comment: Military time or AM/PM is a presentation layer concern. Querying the database takes place outside (below) of the presentation layer so its not relevant. A stored date does not have a format, its only formatted because humans have to visually perceive it (we are not living in the matrix yet). I recommend you do a little light reading on date and date time structures. Take the other advice as well, **always use parameters in your queries that includes Date and DateTime types**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using strings can lead to SQL Injection. Instead, use code like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string here..."))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;

        command.Connection = connection;
        // Next command is your query. 
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE WebDateTime BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        var date1 = new SqlParameter("Date1", SqlDbType.Date);
        var date2 = new SqlParameter("Date2", SqlDbType.Date);

        date1.Value = new DateTime(2017, 2, 7, 20, 19, 0);
        date2.Value = new DateTime(2017, 2, 7, 1, 19, 0);

        command.Parameters.Add(date1);
        command.Parameters.Add(date2);

        connection.Open();

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.                 
    }
}
```

Comment: How about Am/pm or 24 hour clock?  Does my data not have that?    and what is this    new DateTime(2017, 2, 7, 20, 19, 0)      ?    I wish to run 1 hour at a time for the range

Comment: @JeremyMiller - `new DateTime(...)` constructs a new DateTime Object. 2017 is the year, 2 is the month, 7 is the day. 20 is military hour (8pm in this case), 19 is the minute and 0 is the seconds.

Comment: I will not know if `09:18:25.633` is AM or PM  , right?

Comment: @JeremyMiller - Are you saying that, at runtime, you don't know if your date is AM or PM? If so, then this is a UI issue. Somehow you need to allow the user to specify that.